# Two UL elements and Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For the purpose of learning flexbox i did recreation of Google front page in my language. I did it a couple of times because some things were not chear (when to use display: flexbox). But now i hit a wall. How to position footer so that it is on bottom and that Slovenia is on one line, the two UL lists on same line but one on left and one on right?

I put html and body height to 100% and also footer height to 100%. But as i did this the footer jumped up for some reason. Why is that? Slovenia and "Google je na voljo v: English" had been pushed up.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/jernejt/pen/KooWwy

And this is final screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc60l.jpg

Here is my markup (CSS somehow i can not paste it here)

```css
/* Fake Google CSS */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

header ul li {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

header ul li a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  text-decoration: none;
}

header ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#app {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#google_logo {
  width: 272px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 150px 0 30px 0;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 500px;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  width: 528px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 6px 9px 6px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
  font-size: large;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #EAEAEA;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

button:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

main p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1a0dab;
}

main p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  /*Why does this push Slovenia up?*/
}

footer p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

footer ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

footer #neki1 {}

footer #neki2 {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fake Google</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="google.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Slike</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons" id="app">view_module</i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/32x32" alt="User photo"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <main>
    <img id="google_logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/272x92" alt="Google logo">
    <form>
      <input type="text">
      <button>Iskanje Google</button>
      <button>Klik na srečo</button>
    </form>
    <p>Google je na voljo v: <a href="#">English</a></p>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>Slovenija</p>
    <ul id="neki1">
      <li><a href="#">Oglaševanje</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Posel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Predstavitev</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="neki2">
      <li><a href="#">Zasebnost</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pogoji</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nastavitve</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Uporabi Google.com</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The set value of `height` (in a `flex-direction:column` parent) - or `width` (in a `flex-direction:row` parent) is setting the initial value of `flex-basis`.

This means the distribution of free space is starting from:

- `<header>`: 35px
- `<main>`: 460px
- `<footer>`: 100% (of parent height).

Flexbox starts from the initial value of `calc(100% + 495px)`, and tries to shrink them back to `100%`, based on their `flex-shrink` properties. And all three of them have default `flex-shrink` value, which is `1` ( = *shrinkable*).

If you don't want `<footer>` to overlap `<main>`, don't let `<main>` shrink:

```
main {
  flex-shrink: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Andrei's explanation for why your `footer` is overlapping the `main` , if you want the footer to be always in the bottom, reduce its `height` and use `margin-top:auto`

```
main {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

footer{
  height: 50px; // or %
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/f9e74L3c/1/

Comment: I advise against proportional footer or header height. It's such bad UI that no decent websites or commonly used libraries use it. There is no point in header or footer changing height when page height changes. They should only change height when their content changes or re-flows.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i totally agree with you i just wanted to do as minimal changes as possible to the OP's snippet and the point is reducing the `height` whether it's in `px` or `%`

Comment: Well, UI says it should neither grow nor shrink. It should accommodate the contents with sufficient spacing to allow easy interaction by either pointer or touch events. I want to also draw attention to a small detail here, with `margin: auto;`. It breaks normal behavior of `justify-content` property on body, which is commonly used in today's designs, for centering stuff vertically. I'd rather push the footer down with `flex-grow:1` on `<main>` to allow vertical centering between header and footer when needed.

Comment: Actually, that can be easily achieved by `margin:auto` on either `<main>` top or header bottom. Disregard that idea. Cheers!

Comment: `flex-grow:1` on the `main` is good practice too, thnx for pointing that out.